Confusion about spent deceleration energy
Energy is equal to
$$E=F⋅d$$
I have always considered $d$ to be the displacement solely caused by the force $F$. But this idea falls apart when I look at the energy spent to decelerate a moving object.
If an object moving at velocity $v$ undergoes a deceleration $a$ by some force $F$ for a time duration of $t$, then the distance $d$ made by the object in that time duration is
$$d=\frac{1}{2} t(v+(v-at))=vt-\frac{1}{2} at^2$$
The deceleration energy E is then said to be
$$E=F⋅d=F⋅(vt-\frac{1}{2}at^2)$$
My confusion lies in the fact that this distance $d$ is not solely caused by the deceleration force but is a net result of the object’s velocity and the deceleration force combined.
I would therefore think that the true displacement purely caused by the deceleration force is the difference between the above deceleration distance $d$ compared to if the object didn’t go any deceleration, in that same time duration $t$.
$$Δd=vt-(vt-\frac{1}{2}at^2)=\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
From which the deceleration energy is calculated by
$$E=F⋅Δd=F⋅\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
So is the premise about the distance in the energy formula solely being caused by the force wrong in the first place?

The quick answer is that the displacement $d$ is indeed the total displacement of the body (its trajectory, if you will...), it does not matter what force is acting on it and/or is causing the displacement.
It is not that surprising that there is a dependency on the initial speed: remember from the work-energy relationship $$F d = \Delta K,$$ where $K$ is the kinetic energy, so the force (if acting for a fixed amount of time) has to do a different amount of work depending on the actual change in kinetic energy.
And indeed in your case $K_{in}=\frac{1}{2}m v^2$ but $K_{fin}=\frac{1}{2}m (v-at)^2$ so
$$Ld=\Delta K = K_{fin}-K_{in}=\frac{1}{2}m (+a^2t^2-2avt) = -ma(vt-\frac{at^2}{2})$$
and since $F=ma$ we recover your derivation (the sign is negative because the force is opposite to the displacement in this case)
$$Fd = -F(vt-\frac{at^2}{2})$$
In other words, since the object has a different initial (and final) kinetic energy depending on the initial speed $v$, the force has to do a different amount of work (at fixed time $t$). In a time $t$, depending on the (initial) speed, it will act on the body for the same amount of time but over different lengths.
Yet other words, the point is that the difference in initial and final kinetic energy depends on the initial speed, so the work exerted by the force will differ too.


So is the premise about the distance in the energy formula solely being caused by the force wrong in the first place?

Yes. The displacement $d$ in
$E = F \cdot d$
is simply the displacement of the object in the direction of the force $F$. In vector terms, it is the "dot product" of force and displacement:
$E = \vec F . \vec d$
There is no suggestion that the displacement $d$ has to be caused by the force $F$. For example, if a car of mass $m$ drives up a hill of height $h$ then the work done on the car by gravity is $E = -mgh$ (which is equal to its loss in potential energy) but it is the car's engine that is driving it up the hill, not gravity.
